# Replacements for Neural Networks

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I was recently learning about artificial neural networks and their usefulness intrigued me. So I tried to make one that would play a simple game (2048, done many times before so it seemed like a good place to start.)However, I have found two problems along the way.

The first is that the way I am programming it, there is no training data set. This appears to be able to be worked around, but I haven't found a way to do it.

The second is that neural networks, only appear to be able to minimize an error, and with this game you are trying to maximize a score. At any given time there is no optimal setup for the neural net to check against.

I like the ability to create an AI and let it learn the best strategies without me directly teaching it, which is why I decided to try this format in the first place. My question then is, is there a type of NN that can overcome these short fallings, or a way to program one without these issues, or do I just have to switch to a different algorithm/program. If I do have to switch please give a recommendation of what to switch to.

Thank you for any input

Also, if this belongs in a different place in stack exchange please say where

Comment: 1) You can easily create your own dataset by playing the game and saving the game states. I recommend you to implement a minimax / expectimax agent and record the progression of their game. 2) A neural network is a regressor / classifier, and not something that stricly must be minimized. Bonus) I've implemented this before myself. However, expectimax has by far the best performance.

Comment: Thank you, I've never heard of expectimax before, i'll have to go check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a brief answer to your direct questions.  However read after it for my recommendation :)

> The first is that the way I am programming it, there is no training data set. This appears to be able to be worked around, but I haven't found a way to do it.

I don't think not having a training data set at the outset is hindering your ability to have a training set.  I think you could generate your own training set yourself with another program that plays the game without your NN.  However, this might not be what you're looking for.

> The second is that neural networks, only appear to be able to minimize an error, and with this game you are trying to maximize a score. At any given time there is no optimal setup for the neural net to check against.

This also is not a problem, because you could [define your cost function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network#Choosing_a_cost_function) to basically make a higher score have less error.  Perhaps you can determine the theoretical maximum score a "0 error", and a score of 0 be an error of say 100, then create a cost function which fits this model.

What else is there?

"[Reinforcement learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning)" seems to fit most closely with 2048 in my opinion, but like all things AI you won't know until you try and have proof to back it up!  Check it out and see if it's what you're looking for.  A brief quote from the link is below.

> Reinforcement learning differs from standard supervised learning in that correct input/output pairs are never presented...